# Geometry Proximity - distance starts far from selected edge

Tags: geometry-nodes

question is I can't understand why my function getting wrong distance from proximity - seel vertex group on screenshot - it's edge of subdivided mesh, but Proximity node looks like returning 0 for points that are close enough.

How to make it showing distance right to the edge ??

Thank you!

[image]

Detailed:

1. what I do is displace vertices of the cleaning mop mesh (this wavy surface is a floor cleaning cloth) along z axis with geometry - taking the position and displace it with noise - that's how this wavy surface is created.
2. then I need to make the bumpy edge all around the edge
3. I thought that I will just use the proximity from the edge to vertices so that I use formula to create the bumpy edge (blend the "wavy" displacement with "bumpy" displacement
4. how I define the edges fro proximity node: I get join edge loop into vertex grop, then I pick this vertex group and separate its geometry with a node, and send this geometry to proximity node
5. (!) honestly ALMOST everything works on longer distances as expected, but for vertices really close to the edge - happens something strange, see the flat area all along the edge? instead of bumpiness, it's for some reason return (I suppose) zero Z displacement
   And no idea how to fix this.

Thank you much!!

Comment: Hi, Pavel.. welcome. Could you make this a bit clearer? Proximity between those edges, and what, exactly? Maybe if you told us  what you were wanting to use the proximity _for_, that would help us, too.

Comment: @RobinBetts, sure, added in description, thank you!!